# Posting data to the server from highchart points

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highslide

I am trying to post data from highcharts.

```
  point: {
    events: {
        click: function (e) {
            hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                pageOrigin: {
                    x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                    y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                },
                headingText: this.series.name,
                maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' +
                    this.y + ' visits ' + '<div>'+'<button onclick="posting(this.y)">'+'send report' +'</button>'+'</div>',
                width: 200
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling a function on clicking the button and I want to send data to it. How can we send `this.y` to `posting()` function so that we get current point value in the function. [This fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/8zsyg26a/) is showing the `undefined` in alert. How can I achieve the `this.y` value there. Click on the **points** in the chart then click the **send report** button and you will get my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will solve the problem if you use

```
<button onclick="posting('+this.y+')">'+'send report' +'</button>'+'</div>'
```

instead of

```
<button onclick="posting(this.y)">'+'send report' +'</button>'+'</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the this.y value into the string as a variable. check my modification inside the click function at this.y on line 84

http://jsfiddle.net/8zsyg26a/2

```
maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' +
                                        this.y + ' visits ' + '<div>'+'<button onclick="posting(' + this.y + ')">'+'send report' +'</button>'+'</div>',
```